# Can't install Git

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, git, github

Im following the tutorial below to install git.

https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git

However when I get to the end where I need to install the helper into the same directory where Git itself is installed i get the following error:

```
Davids-iMac:~ davidcavanagh$ which git
/usr/bin/git
Davids-iMac:~ davidcavanagh$ sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain /usr/bin
mv: rename git-credential-osxkeychain to /usr/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain: No such file     
or directory
Davids-iMac:~ davidcavanagh$
```

Edit: I am now getting the following error when I install git and then run git -version

```
Davids-iMac:~ davidcavanagh$ git -version
/usr/bin/git: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/usr/bin/git: line 1: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
I was following this tutorial guide:https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git
```

I have also tried using home-brew as well and I get the following error when I do this:

```
Davids-iMac:~ davidcavanagh$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/Library/...
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1

Press ENTER to continue or any other key to abort
==> Downloading and Installing Homebrew...
Failed during: git init -q
```

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying everything I solved this problem by updating the Command Line Tools with Xcode. This can be done here:  https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action# or by going to Xcode--->Preferences----->Downloads

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the program, as it says in the guide a few lines above the code you are having a problem with.

```
git credential-osxkeychain # Test for the cred helper
# git: 'credential-osxkeychain' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

curl -s -O http://github-media-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/osx/git-credential-osxkeychain # Download the helper

chmod u+x git-credential-osxkeychain # Fix the permissions on the file so it can be run
```

Comment: Thanks I did that but now im getting an error at the very end why I try and execute git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain


    Davids-iMac:~ davidcavanagh$ git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
    /usr/bin/git: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
    /usr/bin/git: line 1: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems you have downloaded something else, probably an error page. Download the file http://github-media-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/osx/git-credential-osxkeychain and try again.

Answer (score 1):

On OSX use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install `git`. Once you've installed homebrew with its simple one-liner command, then type these commands:

```
brew update
brew install git
```

Comment: When I try and use homebrew I get: Failed during: git init -q

Answer (score 0):

1. [Download Git Installer](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/list) – The download is titled “Snow Leopard,” but the package works fine with both Lion and Mountain Lion.
2. Open Mac’s “System Preferences” and select “Security & Privacy”
3. Under “Allow applications downloaded from,” make sure “Anywhere” is selected
4. Open DMG downloaded in Step 1 and install the package.
5. Open your terminal and run the following:

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
   sudo ln -s /usr/local/git/bin/git /usr/local/bin/git
   exit
   ```
6. Re-open your terminal and run the following:

   ```
   git –-version
   ```

   usage: git [--version] [--exec-path[=]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
          [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
          [--git-dir=] [--work-tree=] [--namespace=]
          [-c name=value] [--help]
           []
7. You’re good to go...

Comment: Still getting that error after I have followed all those steps!Davids-iMac:~ davidcavanagh$ git -version
/usr/bin/git: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/usr/bin/git: line 1: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'